# Is the apparent slower movement of distant objects compared to nearer ones seen from a speeding train due to basic optical perspective or relativity?

Tags: perception

I was on a rapidly moving train recently and could not read the station signs because they whizzed by so fast. Some buildings in the distance with some business signs seemed to move much slower and were readable, although presumably I was passing them at the same rate of speed. The business signs may have been slightly larger than or about the same size as the station signs, but I think it is the fact they seemed to move slower relative to me that enabled their readability. Perhaps the rotation of my eyes and/or head enabled distant readability slightly. (I have often thought, when sitting in a speeding car and looking out at the scenery, that it is as if I am on a rotating disc moving in one direction, while objects on the horizon are moving in the opposite direction at the edge of such an imagined disc. I gather this effect of portraying objects moving in the viewer’s opposite direction is used in animation. Of course, a train is primarily linear in motion.) I am familiar with YouTube videos explaining relativity train thought experiments, however, as a layman, although relativity comes to mind, I wonder whether the apparent slower movement of objects far away is primarily an aspect of optical perspective. I note that perspective is often associated with a single, stationary viewpoint, whether “classic Renaissance” or curvilinear perspective. I am aware that objects seem to recede into the distance and advance into the foreground with a square equation, but I am unsure if such a mathematical relationship would necessarily also manifest itself in terms of perception in motion. I am aware that relativity governs everything, but I am looking to see if there is a simpler reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you are observing is necessarily basic optical perspective and nothing to do with Special Theory of Relativity because you are moving nowhere near the speed of light. When things are farther away, for a given linear velocity, the angular velocity of it moving across your sight diminishes linearly.

The relevant equation is $$v=r\omega\qquad\implies\qquad\omega=\frac vr$$

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. I'll take a look at linear/angular velocity.